# Generating Random Date

Tags: java, date, object, for-loop, random

I'm a novice Java student. I have only been studying programming for a few months at school, and so I am currently pretty bad at it, and often feel stuck doing my assignments.

Anyway, I have a question regarding an assignment. I have been looking around and not quite finding the answers I need, so I was hoping to find some help on here. It would be much appreciated. My assignment goes like this: "Write a program that creates a Date object and a Random object. Use the Random object to set the elapsed time of the Date object in a loop to 10 long values between `0` and `100000000000` and display the random longs and the corresponding date and time."

We were just introduced to the classes `java.util.Random` and `java.util.Date` to work with this assignment, and are expected to use them to create the needed Date and Random objects.

The only things I really know how to do for this assignment are how to start the code:

```
public class RanDate {

public static void main(String[] args) {
```

And how to create the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
```

I'm sorry if my question was too vague, or if I didn't ask something properly. This is my first time asking for help on this site. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The way this site works is that you try to write the program first, which may require a bit of googling etc. Then you ask a specific question if you encounter a problem...

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. Will do. Thank you.

Comment: read the docs for `Random` and `Date`

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly. These random long values are unix timestamps, right? (elapsed milliseconds since Jan 01 1970)

Comment: Yes, I believe so, cylon.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Date date = new Date(Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - rnd.nextLong()));
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Just subtract the actual time `System.currentTimeMillis()` and random generated long number with `rnd.nextLong()`. It's better finally wrap it all to `Math.abs()`.

Comment: Okay, I will try that out. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I was trying to work with it, but I wasn't sure what you meant by that last sentence, "Just subtract... Math.abs()."

Sorry, I'm still pretty noobish with Java. 8-(

Comment: Literally said: You have the actual date, right now `System.currentTimeMillis()` .. and you generate a random short time duration with `rnd.nextLong()`. If you want to have any date in the past, subtract it: `now - shortTime = timeInPast` .. I am noobish too, we both still learn :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.
I think the assignment asks for the long to be the value in the date object, but I'm not shure.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long max =0L;
        Long min =100000000000L;
        //Use the date format that best suites you
        SimpleDateFormat spf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            Long randomLong=(r.nextLong() % (max - min)) + min;
            Date dt =new Date(randomLong);
            System.out.println("Generated Long:"+ randomLong);
            System.out.println("Date generated from long: "+spf.format(dt));
                    
                    
        }
    }
```

Sample Output:

> Generated Long:68625461379
>
> Date generated from long: 05/03/1972

Comment: I was trying to follow your advice and using what you sent me, but I got an error: "Cannot find symbol; symbol: class SimpleDateFormat."

How do I add it? The same way I add the Date and Random classes?

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to add the class. Thanks a lot for your help. 8-)